# Does a function exist to read [stack] address range of self process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, maps, stack, callstack

is there any function available on linux to get information about the addess range of [stack] information of the current process like as in the /proc/self/maps file [stack] section?
regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no, no such function exists. If you look at the source of the [`pmap`](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/pmap.c?view=markup) utility, you can see that even they just [parse](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/proc/readproc.c?view=markup) the files in the `/proc` filesystem so I'm afraid that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but you may be able to leverage `pstack` (which, sadly, doesn't work on 64bit kernels, IIRC)

http://linux.die.net/man/1/pstack

Comment: i wanted a funtion to be able to read [stack] region of the process. but there is not such funtion.as par my knowledge pstack is a command to dump stack of the specified process..

Comment: @sandeep but it will give you the address. You can then use whatever method (`dd if=/proc/mem` or similar) to get what is at the address. I figured getting the address was the difficult bit